# PHP conditional statement

Tags: php

Hi can someone help me on what i have done wrong in my conditional statement.

```
if(isset($_GET['input'] or $_GET['input2'] or $_GET['input3']))
{
  $release=$_GET['input'].$_GET['input2'].$_GET['input3'];
  echo $release;
}
```

EDIT: ERROR IS `syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR, expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: what this conditional should check?

Comment: Checks if there inputs are set then places them in a variable and echoed out. Normally all inputs have values/has default values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make multiple calls to `isset`, one for every parameter you want to check!

Keep in mind that `or` has a different precedence from `||`, you usually want the latter.

You get a parse error because you pass a compound expression to `isset` and not a variable. It's not a regular function, but a separate language construct which is why it has its own arbitrary rules as pointed out by the docs:

> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error.

---

Perhaps you think that PHP emulates natural languages and you therefore read it as `"Is input or input2 or input3 set?"`.

That would be a misconception. *If* it were valid syntactically, it would logically `OR` the values together at first, and then it would pass that *one value* to `isset`—by that time, all connection to your variables is lost and the only thing that is left is either `true` or `false` onto which `isset` would then be applied.

Comment: What? No you don't. Ever heard of a loop?

Comment: @Kush it's silly to use a loop for this, but of course, technically you could.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(isset($_GET['input']) || isset($_GET['input2']) || isset($_GET['input3']))
```

But I actually think you need AND here, not OR, so change || to && if I am correct.

Comment: I too believe he meant to use AND

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `isset` for each parameter separately. `isset()` accepts single parameter and respond accordingly..

For more details check [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

**Bonus Tip:**
If you are using these variables in database queries, you must use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to avoid possible sql injection

Comment: "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0". Why not just link him to PDO!?

Comment: Ah, the avoid-injection-ever-present-upvote-bringer!
No one talked about database, so that's just a random advice. Oh and he should also be aware of XSS injection and CSRF, since we're at it

Comment: @Kush I thought the person will be able to read more on the page. Anyways, I have updated the link

Answer (score 3):

All the current answers to this question miss an important feature of `isset`: it can check for multiple variables at the same time. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

So in this case you can do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['input'], $_GET['input2'], $_GET['input3'])) {
```

This conditional will only pass if all the `_GET` elements are set.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix your error:

```
if(isset($_GET['input']) or isset($_GET['input2']) or isset($_GET['input3']))
{
    $release=$_GET['input'].$_GET['input2'].$_GET['input3'];
    echo $release;
}
```

But because you're testing OR instead of AND, all you would need is 1 of those OR tests to come back true to get into the if condition - and if either of the other 2 were unset, you'd still throw a notice / error.

To check that all three exist, you'd do something like

```
if (isset($_GET['input']) && isset($_GET['input2']) && isset($_GET['input3'])) { 
    //...
}
```

This probably does what you're trying to achieve without the messy test:

```
// count will return however many key=>val pairs are in the array, 
// 0 will fail
if (count($_GET)) {
    // an empty array and an empty string to hold iterated results
    $get = array();
    $release = '';
    // iterate through $_GET and append each key=>val pair to the local array, 
    // then concat onto the string
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) {
        $get[$key] = $val;
        $release .= $get[$key];
    }
    echo $release;
}
```

HTH :)

---

EDIT: As others indicated, if you need the test to ensure all of those array keys are set, skip the `foreach` loop and just do this:

```
 // extract imports all of the array keys into the symbol table. 
 // It returns the number of symbls imported, and automatically
 // sets vars using keys for var name: 
 if (extract($_GET) && isset($input,$input2,$input3)) {
     echo $release = $input.$input2.$input3;
 }
```

(Using multiple arguments passed to isset.)

- HTH :)